# Arcpy - loop through files in 2 folders to calculate multiple NDVI files

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, loop

I am trying to calculate multiple NDVI files from multiple red band files and NIR band files in 2 separated folders with the following code using python:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *

# set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"F:/..."

# set folder paths
folder1 = r"F:/..."
folder2 = r"F:/..."

# loop through each raster in folder1 and folder2
for raster1 in arcpy.ListRasters("TIF", folder1):
    for raster2 in arcpy.ListRasters("TIF", folder2):
        # create raster objects
        ras1 = Raster(folder1 + "/" + raster1)
        ras2 = Raster(folder2 + "/" + raster2)

        # calculate NDVI
        ndvi = ((ras2 - ras1) / (ras2 + ras1))

        # save NDVI raster
        ndvi.save(r"F:/..." + raster1[:-4] + "_ndvi.tif")
```

The code runs successfully but returns an empty output folder. What could be the reason?

Comment: Have you tried the expression once to make sure it is working?

Comment: When I try it I do not receive any error message and the proces is labeld as 0 (finished).

Answer (score 0):

ListRasters returns a list of  rasters from the env.workspace.  And your wildcard and data types are also wrong.  [See here for more help with list rasters](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listrasters.htm).

This worked for me but you will need to change the work spaces obviously:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy.sa import *
import traceback
import sys

arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
# set workspace



# set folder paths
folder1 = r"C:\gTemp\tester\f1"
folder2 = r"C:\gTemp\tester\f2"
out_dir = "C:\\gTemp\\tester\\"

# loop through each raster in folder1 and folder2
arcpy.env.workspace = folder1
for raster1 in arcpy.ListRasters():
    arcpy.env.workspace = folder2
    for raster2 in arcpy.ListRasters():
        # create raster objects
        ras1 = Raster(folder1 + "/" + raster1)
        ras2 = Raster(folder2 + "/" + raster2)

        # calculate NDVI
        ndvi = ((ras2 - ras1) / (ras2 + ras1))

        # save NDVI raster
        ndvi.save(out_dir + raster1[:-4] + '_ndvi.tif')
print('done')
```